# Whats the difference between Resnet 18 and Resnet 20?

Tags: deep-learning, resnet

I have not been able to get any comparison information between Resnet-18 and Resnet 20. Can someone drop some info on this?

I know the repetition changes for deeper layers. But the difference between specifically these two intrigues me .